# Python (tastypie) - Bad request on POST, returns "error" dict

Tags: python, json, django, http, tastypie

I'm trying to send data to my Django-powered server using Tastypie.

I have this model

```
class Open(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()
```

and this URLconf

```
open_resource=OpenResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(open_resource.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

when I run the tastypie curl command

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name","awdawd"}' http://localhost:8000/api/open/
```

I get the error

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Sat, 05 Apr 2014 12:18:48 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json

{"error": ""}
```

I've tried everything and can't seem to get this working.

Does anyone have a clue on this one?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you tried with GET ? Is it working or giving the same error ?.. By default only GET will be allowed but in that case should have returned a 501 or 405 not 400 .. Just to be sure Please try with GET once

Answer (score 2):

I get this unhelpful error whenever I provide **invalid JSON data**.

***Correct*** JSON format is:

```
{"foo": "bar"}                     // correct!

[{"foo": "bar"}, {"fiz": "baz"}]   // correct!

{"foo": "bar", "fiz": "baz"}       // correct!
```

Examples of common *mistakes*:

```
{'foo': 'bar'}    // error is using single quotes instead of double quotes
{foo: "bar"}      // error is not using double quotes for "foo"
{"foo", "bar"}    // error is using a comma (,) instead of a colon (:)  ← Your error
```

Examples of more complex *mistakes*:

```
[{"foo": "bar"}, {"fiz": "baz"},]
// error is using a comma at the end of a list or array

{"foo": "bar", "fiz": "baz",}  // courtesy @gthmb
// error is using a comma at the end of the final key-value pair
```

Think your JSON is valid? Double-check with a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I had an extra comma following the final element in an object, which was causing the error. It's a rather unhelpful error to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

As tastypie works with JSON data you have to provide also this format.
Try this as data:

```
--data '{"name": "myName"}'
```

Also I'm not sure how you build your urls, but I can show you a working url set up:

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(OpenResource())
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
...
}
```

This would create the following url to access your resource:

```
/api/v1/open/?format=json
```

This would finally come to this curl command:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name": "myName"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/open/
```

And don't forget to add the authorisation and authentication in your metadata of your resource

```
OpenResource(ModelResource)
    class Meta:
    queryset = Open.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
```

As by default tastypie sets up a resource with the ReadOnlyAuthorization, which forbids post, put access.

For more information read the docs: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org

Hopefully this helped, cheers!